# Large performance difference on Pentium D vs. i5 (Infragistics UltraCombo control v10.3)

Tags: c#, winforms, intel, infragistics

I am using the UltraCombo control on a WinForm (Infragistics v10.3). The code is c# and built on .Net 4.0. I have a list of 58,000 items that I am binding to the control. Here is the code:

In the form load event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 58000; i++)
{
    Requester r = new Requester();
    r.AccountId = i;
    r.AccountNumber = i.ToString();
    r.ContactGroupId = i;
    r.Deactivated = false;
    r.DefaultContactId = i;
    r.FacilityId = i;
    r.PriceModelId = i;
    r.RequesterId = i;
    r.RequesterName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    r.RequesterTypeId = i;

    requesters.Add(r);
}
```

In the BeforeDropDown event of the control:

```
if (!_requestersLoaded)
{
    var currentRequester = string.Empty;
    requesterUltraCombo.DataSource = requesters.OrderBy(t => t.RequesterName).ToList<Requester>();
    requesterUltraCombo.Text = currentRequester;
}
```

The Requester Class itself is very simple:

```
public class Requester
{
    public Requester(){}

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int ContactGroupId { get; set; }
    public bool Deactivated { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultContactId { get; set; }
    public int? FacilityId { get; set; }
    public int PriceModelId { get; set; }
    public int RequesterId { get; set; }
    public string RequesterName { get; set; }
    public int RequesterTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

The code in the BeforeDropdown event executes in roughly 5-6 seconds on a Pentium i5 2.6 GHz with affinity set to only 1 core. For purposes of this question, this level of performance is completely acceptable.

The same code executes in 20-25 seconds on a dual-Pentium D 3 GHz, with affinity set to both CPUs. It is even slower when affinity is set to only 1 CPU.

I assume the difference is related to the CPUs, but, what I am not sure of is what aspect(s) of the CPU's may be the leading cause here? This is not my area of expertise.

Is it the slower cache on the Pentium D? 
IS it the fact that the Pentium D does not have separate data and instruction caches?
Is it that the Pentium D does not employ hyperthreading?
Is it some combination of these aspects, plus others? I assume this may be the case.

Comment: Pentium D is several generations behind all of the i-whatever series. A 4x difference is not surprising at all.

Comment: LOL. 58k items in a ComboBox. That's a really good idea. Reminds me of some IBM issue tracking software I used a long time ago. Don't blame the CPU for that.